# Viewing jpeg from LDAP via PHP

Tags: php, encoding, ldap, base64

I store contacts photo in openLDAP. All works fine, but i cant get jpegPhoto in base64 format (like ldapsearch output it) with PHP.

Part of ldapsearch -x:

```
*# 1486, People, domain.name
dn: uidNumber=0000,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=name
objectClass: someUnit
uidNumber: 0000
gidNumber: 0000
loginShell: /bin/false
cn:: Anon
roomNumber:: 000
telephoneNumber: 00-00-00 00-00
departmentNumber:: 000
jpegPhoto:: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAtAC0AAD/4QzsRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAIAA4BAgAgAAAAbg
 AAAA8BAgAGAAAAjgAAABABAgAPAAAAlAAAADIBAgAUAAAApAAAABMCAwABAAAAAgCaOwEQAwABAAA
 A4BAAAAIQAwABAAAAqAwAAGmHBAABAAAAuAAAAAAAAAAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
 ICAgICAgAENhbm9uAENhbm9uIElYVVMgMTMwAAAyMDExOjAyOjE3IDE0OjU3OjE5AB8AmoIFAAEAA
 AAyAgAAnYIFAAEAAAA6AgAAJ4gDAAEAAACQAc3/AJAHAAQAAAAwMjIxA5ACABQAAABCAgAABJACAB
 QAAABWAgAAAZEHAAQAAAABAgMAApEFAAEAAABqAgAAAZIKAAEAAAByAgAAApIFAAEAAAB6AgAABJI
 KAAEAAACCAgAABZIFAAEAAACKAgAAB5IDAAEAAAAFAEH/CZIDAAEAAAAYAED/CpIFAAEAAACSAgAA
 .............................................................................
```

PHP code for data output:

```
$ds = ldap_connect('localhost', 389)
          or die("Невозможно соединиться с $ldaphost");
$justthese = array("cn", "roomNumber", "telephoneNumber","departmentNumber","mail","jpegPhoto");
$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $justthese);
$entry = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
$i=0;

//Formation of the table header

..............................................................

do {

    $matches = "";

// Output "cn", "roomNumber", "telephoneNumber","departmentNumber"

    echo "<td style=\"border-right:1px solid lightgray; \" align=\"center\">".$entry[$i]["departmentnumber"][0]."</td>";
    echo "<td style=\"padding-left:20px;\"><a href=\"mailto:".$entry[$i]["mail"][0]."\">".$entry[$i]["mail"][0]."</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo $entry[$i]["jpegphoto"][0];


    $i++;
} while ($i<count($entry)-1);
echo "</table>";

ldap_close($ds);
```

I want to get base64 $entry[$i]["jpegphoto"][0] equal: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAtAC0AAD/4QzsRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAIAA4BAgAgAAAAbgAAAA8BAgAGAAAAjgAAABABAgAPAAAAlAAAADIBAgAUAAAApAAAABMCAwABAAAAAgCaOwEQAwABAAA..."

But I result is:
"����JFIF�����ExifII* n��2��;��i�� CanonCanon IXUS 1302011:02:16 10:51:57��2��:'���0221�B�V��j� r�z� ����  �Y ��|�*  �����0100����������r^�#&�$'&�! �!������KH2 2011:02:16 10:51:572011:02:16 10:51:57� � � =�04��"���b      , �L�&1�Zbb    E�   "� #�'    �(��-.�/�`��@��� N������ ���������=��D�z���`�� �IMG:IXUS 130 JPEGFirmware Version 1.00����Q����������?  (p1p�@1p g����,�`F�`F����Fz�?)�EW���@p����@>���������������������������������������������������Q8,���� ���@p�O������� �2_b    ��@�R555����R5`5`5��$�)5: F&5( ��������Xh�                ""     $'))'$ #(,--,( *.//.* *.//.*% (,--,(#  $'))'$    ""          ����pc�b���q��������"@u���II*��A�@p1�����C             ��C      ����"��  ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� "

Comment: It looks like you are getting the raw bytes (as in, the decoded data), so you should call `base64_encode` on your variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grampa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467867/viewing-jpeg-from-ldap-via-php#comment47097901_29467867) was right, I was getting the raw bytes of the image. `base64_encode`-ing the output worked:

```
$lil = base64_encode($entry[$i]["jpegphoto"][0]);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$lil.'"/>';
```

Comment: @Blackhole Grampa posted a comment with part of the solution -- I think this is a fair standalone answer with some editing.

Comment: @hichris123 With the explanation you've just added, that's a far better answer, indeed!